# How to convert xml data to json data using FluentD

Tags: json, xml, plugins, fluentd

I'm trying to stream log files using FluentD.
Now I'm testing it in my window server, which is running on VM UTM, before I make changes in production.

This is what I've done so far. The output folder is empty and no file was created.

1. Installed `fluent-plugin-xml-parser` plugin following https://github.com/toyokazu/fluent-plugin-xml-parser
2. Checked if it was installed by running `td-agent-gem list` and it showed that the version of 1.0.0 was installed.
3. My `td-agent.conf` looks like the following

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path C:/xml/input/input.xml
  pos_file C:/xml/input/input.xml.pos
  tag test.xml
  <parse>
    @type xml
  </parse>
</source>

<match test.xml>
  @type file
  path_suffix ".json"
  path C:/xml/output/
  append true
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>
```

I can see the error message in `td-agent.log`

```
[error]: config error file="C:\\opt\\td-agent\\etc\\td-agent\\td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::NotFoundPluginError error="Unknown parser plugin 'xml'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

As the error message suggested I ran `gem search -rd fluent-plugin` and I can see it's installed.

```
fluent-plugin-xml-parser (1.0.0)
    Authors: Toyokazu Akiyama, Brendan McGrath
    Homepage: http://github.com/toyokazu/fluent-plugin-xml-parser

    fluentd xml parser plugin
```

I'm not sure why it complained about it and failed to create the output file.

Comment: You might want to verify your config according to the version of `td-agent` installed as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/toyokazu/fluent-plugin-xml-parser#usage). Apart from that, according to this [comment](https://github.com/toyokazu/fluent-plugin-xml-parser/issues/1#issuecomment-281720534), this plugin needs the complete XML for successful parsing. The `tail` input reads lines separated by newlines which might not what is expected by that plugin. You may have to minify the complete XML file as one single line to make it work with `tail`.